# Passing state when using decorators (formencode) in pylons

Tags: pylons, decorator, state, formencode

I've met the same problem as this page:

http://www.mail-archive.com/pylons-discuss@googlegroups.com/msg14292.html

This is the main content from there:

> I am using formencode to validate my
>   forms, and I've stumbled upon a
>   problem. When using tha validator
>   inside the controller action, I call
>   to_python() and I can pass the state
>   variable with any information I need
>   to the validators. Is it possible to
>   do the same with the validate
>   decorator?

From the answers of there, they said it has not been fixed in pylons, but that was several months agao. I wanna if there any solutions for it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pylons.decorators.validate(schema=None, validators=None, form=None, variable_decode=False, dict_char='.', list_char='-', post_only=True, state=None, on_get=False, **htmlfill_kwargs)
```

Note the `state` parameter. Full docs [here](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/modules/decorators/#pylons.decorators.validate) (Pylons 1.0)

Comment: After some searchs, I found there are some limitations with validation decorator, we can't pass dynamic state to it (via @validate). Instead, we can only invoke it as a method, but which looks not as good as decorator